# How to Group Counted Data

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have 3 categories (Below SLA, Near SLA, Over SLA) that has different conditions, I try to count the data but the result is not summarized by their category

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    B.province AS 'PROVINCE',
    CASE
        WHEN TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) < '20:00:00' THEN COUNT(TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time))
    END AS 'Below SLA',
    CASE
        WHEN (TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) > '20:00:00') AND (TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) < '24:00:00') THEN COUNT(TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time))
    END AS 'NEAR SLA',
    CASE
        WHEN TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) > '24:00:00' THEN COUNT(TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time))
    END AS 'OVER SLA'
FROM
    deli_order A
INNER JOIN 
    deli_order_delivery B on A.id = B.order_id
WHERE
    (DATE(A.plat_create_time) BETWEEN '2019-03-30' AND'2019-04-07') AND (TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY B.province;
```

and this is the result that i got:

```
Province       | Below SLA | Near SLA | Over SLA
------------------------------------------------
Bali                30          Null      Null
```

30 is the total of all the records of 'Bali', but its actually divided into 19 Below SLAs, 5 Near SLAs, and 6 Over SLAs.

What should i change in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    B.province AS 'PROVINCE',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN TIMEDIFF(A.deli_time, A.create_time) < '20:00:00' THEN 1
    END) AS 'Below SLA',
```

Put an aggregate function for each case,OUTSIDE of it.I did it for just one case,it`s all the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! Never cross my mind to use aggregate function outside of case.

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo, just FYI, as a newcomer to the site, if you find an answer solves your issue, it is common to mark the solution as solved by the checkbox.  It helps others under similar condition know what did vs not work.

Comment: @DRapp where is the checkbox? I'm sorry, I'm new to this site